# IntelHaxm-Android doesnt get installed , what next?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I was trying to launch android emulator in new android studio version 1.0. But every time I start to launch it says I need to install intelHaxm and I searched and found that my processors doesnt support it, so what next? Can any one suggest?

Comment: Which processor do you have?

Comment: See in Add/Remove program in control panel. click on add/remove feature and uninstall Hyper-V (if installed). Probably help you.

Comment: intel core duo t2450 2 ghz

Comment: Did u install Intel Haxm from
sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager?

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to BIOs setting in enable Virtualization Technology
2. Go to sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and install it.

Comment: I said my processor doesnt support it and thats why I dont have these options